# Create image from "src" coming from html in c#

Tags: c#, html

I want to know how to create an image object having the "src info from an email". I already manage to get read the inbox, and to parse the html of it, and get out all of the "src = foo" from all the images in the email. My question is how do I then proceed to create an image using the information taken out from "src" in the  of the html. I need this object in order to store it in a sharepoint picture library. Just want to know how to create the image object of the image stored in the html of the email.

Comment: Are you asking how to use `data:` URIs, how to read multi-part MIME messages, how to read images from remote URLs, how to write images to known locations for URLs, or something else entirely?

Comment: what does the URL look like in the raw HTML email?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how to put it in SharePoint, but assuming you have a src in an `extractedSrc` variable:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(extractedSrc, localFileName)
```

Comment: the images are attachments in the email. I use html agility pack to parse the html, but no point if the pictures are attached. Am looking at the Extended Web Service Api documentation and found that its possible to take the attachments file of an email. But having the information of the attachment file, how do i proceed in creating the image in c#

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two basic cases you have to consider, 1. The src attribute points to an external image (ie. image stored on a web site), 2. Src points to an image attached in the email.

For case 1. You need to download the image from the external server and then you can save it in your share point

For case 2. You have to decode the attachment sections of the email to extract the file data and then you can save it to your library

Comment: its case 2. the images are attached to the email. Right know am looking how to take the attachments of the email using Extended Web Service Api. If u have any ideas how to do this they are much appreciate. Lets say i extract the name of the attachment for example "picture.jpg", having this store in a string how do i proceed to create the image in c#?